# Javascript Focus using .focus()

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have issue about the focus on javascript if if time_start > 24 the java script alert showed then focus or autofocs it on that textbox. but the focus is not working i don`t know why this is minor problem but please check this.

**javascript**

```
 function start_time(){

   var time_start = document.getElementById("start_t").value;
    if(time_start > 24){
        alert("Invalid Start time hours");
         document.getElementById('start_t').focus();
  } 
 }
```

**html**

```
 <input type="text" size="2" value="00" name="start" id="start_t" style="text-align: center;" onchange="start_time()">:
```

I want to do is in the value is invalid automatically focus on that textbox

Comment: "00" is a string and not an integer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know a solution that works but don't have a valid reason for its working. There are two problems with your code

1. comparing String with Integer

   ```
   function start_time(){
       var time_start = document.getElementById("start_t").value; 
       // time_start is a string. convert it into Integer first
       if(time_start > 24){ // you are comparing integer with string
           alert("Invalid Start time hours");
           document.getElementById('start_t').focus();
     } 
   }
   ```

   you need to change this function as below

   ```
   function start_time(){
        var time_start = parseInt(document.getElementById("start_t").value;
        if(isNaN(time_start) || time_start > 24){ 
            alert("Invalid Start time hours");
            document.getElementById('start_t').focus();
        }             
   }
   ```
2. Doing focus on `change` event. For `input type='text'` change event is fired on blur. I have faced the problems whenever I put the field on focus using JavaScript on the 'change' event. see the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/su9SL/2/). To overcome the problem there are two solutions,

   a. either do the stuff you are doing on click of a button, see the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/su9SL/)

   b. or do the focus with a timeout, [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/su9SL/1/)

   ```
   setTimeout( function() { document.getElementById('start_t').focus()} ,1);
   ```

PS: Please mind my use of jQuery in the fiddles, I am a little lazy in using the native JavaScript functions

Answer (score 3):

Your values are strings and you're comparing integers. You need to parse the value and convert it into an integer.

Change:

```
var time_start = document.getElementById("start_t").value;
```

To:

```
var time_start = parseInt(document.getElementById("start_t").value, 10);
```

If you're using jQuery like your tags suggest you should be doing this.

```
var time_start = parseInt($('#start_t').val(), 10);
```

Also if you're using jQuery you can set the focus to an element like this:

```
$('#start_t').focus();
```

Try to switch your alert to a confirmation dialog so that you have a return value and then set the focus.

Please change this:

```
if (time_start > 24) {
    alert("Invalid Start time hours");
    document.getElementById('start_t').focus();
}
```

To this:

```
if (time_start > 24) {
    var r = confirm("Invalid Start time hours");

    if (r) {
        $('#start_t').focus();
    }  
}
```

Check out this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/sm4Nk/

Comment: if the start_t is above to 24 that textbox is automatically focus. 
this is i want to do sir

Comment: _The way JavaScript works is that it's going show you the alert dialog and then set the focus to your element immediately after showing the alert. JavaScript is not going to wait for your input on the alert dialog it will continue execution the script._
This is not true, please check the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/su9SL/)